# Not able to view design file.ADT update not available

Tags: android

I have an application in that I tried to see an XML file of a login activity but when i clicked Graphical layout it gave me a message stating "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in".Hence I tried to update my ADT going into Help->Install new software but its showing me that there are no updates available can somebody help me on this?And what I should do to see my XML file

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your xml-> select graphical layout ->In that right top corner in 
dropdown select API 19 or below..
```